# Is it Possible to Align dijit.layout.TabContainer Tabs to the Right?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want the tabs to float right, not appear on the right hand side of the content pane. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such option for `tabPosition` property (only `top`, `bottom`, `left-h` and `right-h`), but you need just few lines of JavaScript to achieve this:
[image]

See the code in action at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/aGCFs/

The first idea I had was to override dijit CSS to align tabs with `text-align:right`, but that would not work, because tabs' domNodes are children of `div` which `width` is over 50000px, so tabs won't be visible. To fix this you should set `left` property as well every time the tab container is resized (via `dojo.connect`):

```
var alignTabs = function(tabContainer) {
    var tabListNode = tabContainer.tablist.domNode;
    var tabStripNode = dojo.query("div.nowrapTabStrip", tabListNode)[0];   

    var tabListCoords = dojo.coords(tabListNode);
    var tabStripCoords = dojo.coords(tabStripNode);

    var tabStripLeft = (-tabStripCoords.w + tabListCoords.w) + "px";

    dojo.style(tabStripNode, "textAlign", "right");
    dojo.style(tabStripNode, "left", tabStripLeft);
}

var tabContainer1 = dijit.byId("tabContainer1");
alignTabs(tabContainer1);

dojo.connect(tabContainer1, "resize", function() {
    alignTabs(tabContainer1);            
});
```

It surely needs some fine-tuning, but you have an idea. As this is just an ad hoc code I would suggest subclassing `TabContainer` & `TabController` classes or extending (via `dojo.extend` || `dojo.mixin`) them to bake the feature in.

Also, please note, that I did not test whether this does or does not break the functionality of `ScrollingTabController` for the cases not all tabs fit on a single row.